# Deploy QtWebkit without Qml

Tags: qt, deployment, qtwebkit

I have qt widget application, which uses webkit. When I deploy it, I should include a lot of qt dlls - qml, quick, sensors, positioning, sql - which I do not use. Actually, verifying with Dependency Walker shows, that those dependencies are due to webkit. Is there any way to exlclude those libraries from dependencies?

Comment: Are you using Qt5? The easiest way to do it would be to use Qt4.8.X which has no dependencies on QML unless you're using it.

Comment: Yes, Qt5... And Qt4.8 is no choice, unfortunately